# Insert several Autotext items in order - vba Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working with a Macro enable Word 2016.
I have a macro that will insert several AutoText entries (4) which are entered in a loop. This portion is working ok but I notice that they are not entered in order.

The reason why they're not entered in order is because in each loop iteration I always reference a specific bookmark (as a range). I wonder if there is a way to update the range at each iteration so the AutoText entries are entered one after the other ones?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add code of the loop you insert the AutoText blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I found a way to do this. What I did was the following:

- Moved the selection (cursor) to the desired bookmark
- Insert the AutoText at the Selection.range location
- For all the next items, I always used the Selection.range instead of using the bookmark, since the Selection (cursor) will update as I'm adding text.